# How do you send all your email content from Outlook 2011 for Mac to a Gmail account?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook

I have two email accounts. The first is is Outlook 2011 on my Macbook. The second is an online Gmail account. I prefer Gmail and it's search options. Is there an easy way to send the entire contents of my Outlook to Gmail? I want it for ease of use and as a back up.

Comment: What is Outlook connecting to in order to get mail?

Comment: You can use Gmail to retrieve e-mail from your first account for you. Then, you can just use Gmail exclusively online, or on Outlook connected to the Gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

Two phases you will want to do.

1. Add your Gmail account as IMAP to Outlook. Then copy/move your Outlook emails to the Gmail account you made in Outlook.
2. If you leave Outlook running all the time you can make a rule to [forward all email to your Gmail](http://web.archive.org/web/20150327045259/http://everydaylife.globalpost.com/automatically-forward-email-messages-outlook-mac-23058.html).

If you don't, talk to your email host (work,isp...) about doing a forward on your email.